# Dynamically getting an exported const in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic

I was wondering if I can declare constants in my typescript code like this:

```
export const mapperOne = new Map<string, string>([
['A', 'AA'],
['B','BB']
]);

export const mapperTwo = new Map<string, string>([
['Y', 'YYY'],
['Z','ZZZ']
]);
```

And then dynamically get them by their name.

```
if(case1) { 
  getConstant('mapperOne').get('A')
}
else { 
  getConstant('mapperTwo').get('Y')
}
```

I thought maybe with reflection, but all the examples got class-variables with reflection and not constants that aren't in any class, but just defined in a typescript file.

I also read that in javascript you can get constants by using `window['constantName']`, but for me that results in `undefined`.

Is there a way to do what I need in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually isn't related so much to typescript nor angular. It's more a JavaScript question.

What about:

constants.ts

```js
const mapperOne = new Map<string, string>([
  ['A', 'AA'],
  ['B','BB']
]);

const mapperTwo = new Map<string, string>([
  ['Y', 'YYY'], 
  ['Z','ZZZ']
]);

type Container = {
    'mapperOne': typeof mapperOne;
    'mapperTwo': typeof mapperTwo;
};

const container: Container = { mapperOne, mapperTwo };

export function getConstant(name: keyof Container) {
   return container[name];
}
```

somewhereelse.ts

```js
import { getConstant } from './constants.ts'

const strValue = getConstant('mapperOne').get('A');
```

or even better you could just skip the consts and:

```
 const container = {
    mapperOne: new Map<string, string>([
      ['A', 'AA'],
      ['B','BB']
    ]),
    mapperTwo: new Map<string, string>([
      ['Y', 'YYY'], 
      ['Z','ZZZ']
    ])
};

export function getConstant(name: keyof typeof container) {
   return container[name];
}
```

Comment: You lose the exact return type. Now `getConstant` return type is union of all `container` object values.

Comment: @KiraLT I was just following what *Julia* wrote. If you posted your comment a moment later you would have seen the last part that I've added. Anyways, thanks for the concern.

Comment: Thanks! This was pretty helpful. I thought I might get around nesting my mappers in an object, but I guess I wouldn't be much of an issue to just do it like you did :)

Comment: @Julia you are welcome. It's almost the same. The difference is that when you have a const you cannot change the value of this variable. In the case when you are using a container you actually can change the container properties if you expose the container itself but since you will be using a closure (`getConstant`) you isolate the container so that can't happen. If you want to expose the container so you can use it directly and you want to be sure that you cannot modify its properties you can use `export const c = Object.freeze(container)` in order to do a shallow property freeze.

Answer (score 1):

You can use import all statement: `import * as constans from './contants'`

#### contants.ts

```
export const mapperOne = new Map<string, string>([
    ['A', 'AA'],
    ['B','BB']
]);

export const mapperTwo = new Map<string, string>([
    ['Y', 'YYY'],
    ['Z','ZZZ']
]);
```

Then you can write a simple get function with full typing support:

#### scripts.ts

```
import * as constans from './contants'

function getConstant<K extends keyof typeof constans>(key: K): (typeof constans)[K] {
    return constans[key]
}

getConstant('mapperOne').get('aaa')
```

> In this example I use template literals to automatically detect response type by the given key.

### You can also put everything in one container:

```
const constans = {
    mapperOne: new Map<string, string>([
      ['A', 'AA'],
      ['B','BB']
    ]),
    mapperTwo: new Map<string, string>([
      ['Y', 'YYY'], 
      ['Z','ZZZ']
    ])
};

function getConstant<K extends keyof typeof constans>(key: K): (typeof constans)[K] {
    return constans[key]
}

getConstant('mapperOne').get('A')
```